# Duplicate of doc data created when trying to retrieve document data from firestore database in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I've been tackling this issue for some days now but to no avail. I stored some images and other descriptions related to the images in my firestore database. But each time I try to retrieve the data from the database, it duplicates all the documents and then displays all the images twice after.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getDoc, doc, onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore';
import db from '../firebase';

const Detail = () => {

    const {id} = useParams();
    const [detailData, setDetailData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        
        // const getData = async () => {
            
        //     const movieRef = doc(db, "movies", id);
            
        //     try {
        //         setDetailData([]);
        //         const doc = await getDoc(movieRef);
        //         setDetailData(doc.data());
        //         console.log(detailData);
        //         return;
        //     } catch (e) {
        //         alert("Error getting cached document:", e);
        //     }
        //     };
        //     getData();

             const docRef = doc(db, "movies", id);
                onSnapshot(docRef, (doc) => {
                    if(doc.exists){
                        setDetailData(doc.data());
                        console.log(detailData);
                    } else{
                        console.log("no such document in firebase");
                    }
                })
    }, [id]);

  return (

    <Container>
        <Background>
            <img src={detailData.backgroundImg} alt={detailData.title} />
        </Background>

        <ImageTitle>
            <img src={detailData.titleImg} alt={detailData.title} />
        </ImageTitle>

        <ContentMeta>

            <Controls>

                <Player>
                    <img src="/images/play-icon-black.png" alt="play button" />
                    <span>Play</span>
                </Player>

                <Trailer>
                    <img src="/images/play-icon-white.png" alt="trailer button" />
                    <span>Trailer</span>
                </Trailer>

                <AddList>
                    <span/>
                    <span/>
                </AddList>

                <GroupWatch>
                    <div>
                        <img src="/images/group-icon.png" alt="group icon" />
                    </div>
                </GroupWatch>

            </Controls>

            <SubTitles>
                {detailData.subTitle || 'Subtitles'}
            </SubTitles>

            <Description>
                {detailData.description ||'Description'}
            </Description>
        </ContentMeta>

    </Container>

  );

}

const Container = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 250px);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: block;
    top: 72px;
    padding: 0 calc(3.5vw + 5px);

`;

const Background = styled.div`
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;

    img{
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;

         /* @media (max-width: 768px) {
            object-fit: cover; 
             width: initial;
        }   */
    }
`;

const ImageTitle = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 30vw;
    min-height: 170px;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
    width: 100%;

    img{
        max-width: 600px;
        min-width: 200px;
        width: 35vw;

    }
`;

const ContentMeta = styled.div`
    max-width: 874px;
`;

const Controls = styled.div`
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    margin: 24px 0px;
    min-height: 56px;

`;

const Player = styled.button`
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0px 22px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 24px;
    height: 56px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    justify-content: center;
    letter-spacing: 1.8px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: rgb(249, 249, 249);
    border: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);

    img{
        width: 32px;
    }

    &:hover{
        background: rgb(198, 198, 198);
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px){
        height: 45px;
        padding: 0px 12px;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;

        img{
            width: 25px;
        }
    }
`;

const Trailer = styled(Player)`
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border: 1px solid rgb(249, 249, 249);
    color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
`;

const AddList = styled.div`
    margin-right: 16px;
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid white;
    cursor: pointer;

    span{
        background-color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
        display: inline-block;

        &:first-child{
            height: 2px;
            transform: translate(1px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
            width: 16px;
        }

        &:nth-child(2){
            height: 16px;
            transform: translateX(-8px) rotate(0deg);
            width: 2px;
        }
    }
`;

const GroupWatch = styled.div`
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: white;

    div{
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        border-radius: 50%;

        img{
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
`;

const SubTitles = styled.div`
    color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
    font-size: 15px;
    min-height: 20px;

    @media (max-width:768px) {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
`;

const Description = styled.div`
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 16px 0px;
    color: rgb(249, 249, 249);

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
`;

export default Detail;
```

Now, the images contained inside this Trending row and other similar movie rows all get displayed twice when I go back to the home page:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectTrending } from '../features/movie/movieSlice';

const Trending = (props) => {

  const movies = useSelector(selectTrending);

  return (

    <Container>
        <h4>Trending</h4>

        <Content>

            {
                movies && movies.map((movie, key) => (
                    <Wrap key={key}>
                        {movie.id}
                        <Link to={`/detail/` + movie.id}>
                            <img src={movie.cardImg} alt={movie.title} />      
                        </Link>
                    </Wrap>
                ))
            }

        </Content>

    </Container>

  )

};

const Container = styled.div`
    padding: 0 0 26px;
`;

const Content = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 25px;
    gap: 25px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));

    @media (max-width: 768px){
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
    }
`;

const Wrap = styled.div`
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 69%) 0px 26px 30px -10px,
        rgb(0 0 0 / 73%) 0px 16px 10px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) 0s;
    border: 3px solid rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.1);

    img{
        inset: 0px;
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        opacity: 1;
        position: absolute;
        transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0s;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
    }

    &:hover{
        box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 80%) 0px 40px 58px -16px,
            rgb(0 0 0 / 72%) 0px 30px 22px -10px;
            transform: scale(1.05);
            border-color: rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.8);
    }
`;

export default Trending;
```

Comment: so if I get this right, it duplicates only when you go back to the screen that has the `Detail` component?. What happens if you are on the `Detail` component and you hit refresh ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I figured it out after reading about it on twitter. Apparently React version 18 renders useEffect twice during test mode but not in production mode, which explains why it did not render twice when I deployed the site online. I also found out that you can bypass this or temporarily disable this by removing the React.strictMode tags in the index.js file. I just discovered your reply today but thanks again for the response